# How to correctly write a path to stylesheets in application layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to include my **bootstrap.min.css** file to the project and that is located in **(project)/css/bootstrap.min.css** folder.
I added the following line in application layout between `<head>` tags.

```
<head>
  <title>Greenbull</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
```

However when I run my app, console renders an error
[image]

[image]

Why is that so?

[image]

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="#{Rails.root}/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: add your css files inside app/assets/stylesheets folder and then add to application.css file

Comment: Read from this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned the preferred way of including assets into a rails application is to use the Asset Pipeline. In the event you need to include an asset that lives outside of the default include paths setup by Rails (in your case css/bootstrap.min.css) you can add a custom path to the application.

By adding the following to your config/initializers/assets.rb:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("css")
```

Rails will now look for assets in /css when using the javascript_include_tag or the stylesheet_link_tag within your layout/application.html.erb. You will also need to tell rails the name of the asset to precompile since you are using a filename other than application.js or application.css. To do this add the following to the config/initializers/assets.rb file:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap.min.css )
```

In your layout/application.html.erb you will now be able to tell rails to load your stylesheet.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'bootstrap.min', media: 'all' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Placae your .css in assets/stylesheets folder and then require in application.css

```
*= require your_css_file
```